# jQuery's event.target not working from inside a function

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="javascript:getClassName();" class="link">Click here</a>
```

I know it is possible to get the class name with the code below:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
})
```

I want to be able to use `$(this)` inside a function called `getClassName()` with the help of `event.target`. But, this doesn't seem to work. I always get an error:

> target is undefined

The function that I'm using is:

```
function getClassName(event) {
    el = $(event.target);
    alert(el.attr('class'));
}
```

**And I don't want to use the `event.target` binding on `$(body)`.**

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you want to obtain? "link" in the example? Or value of target attribute of the anchor being clicked? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="javascript:getClassName(this);" class="link">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Hey Praveen, Thanks for your comment. But for some reason even after I passed (this) as a parameter, I get the alert which says 'undefined'

Comment: @Roshan pass event to the function instead of this

Comment: I'm passing **event** in the defined function and **this** where i'm calling it. Still, no luck... Anyways, thank you guys for your help